# maxCDN for google api client library

Tags: javascript, src, google-api-client

is there any max cdn that i can use for this npm command - `npm install --save googleapis`?

i want to run this javascript code without installing the node_modules for the google api client library

```
app.get("/accessTokens", (req,res) => {

  let {google} = require('googleapis');
  let privateKey = require("./google_key.json");

  // configure a JWT auth client
  let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privateKey.client_email,
    null,
    privateKey.private_key,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Error');
    } else {
      return res.send(token.access_token);
    }
  });
})
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks